Arithmetic mapped number literal type
In TypeScript, is it possible to apply an arithmetic mapping function to a number literal type?
Minimum reproducible contrived (but illustrative) case:
type ternary =
  | 0
  | 1
  | 2
;

/**
 * DESIRED: Offset number literal type 'ternary' by 1.
 *
 * Pseudo-notation:
 *
 * type ternaryR = ternary + 1;
 */

// manual typing so code transpiles
type ternaryR =
  | 1
  | 2
  | 3
;

const buffer: [
  number, // metadata
  [number, number],
  [number, number],
  [number, number],
] = [
  10001337,
  [11, 12],
  [21, 22],
  [31, 32],
]

function safeIncrement(
  i: ternaryR,
) {
  const iNext = i + 1;
  if (
    Number.isInteger(iNext)
    && iNext > 0
    && iNext < 4
  )
    return i + 1 as ternaryR;
  else
    throw new RangeError("");
}

for (
  let i: ternaryR = 1;
  i < 4;
  i = safeIncrement(i);
)
  // trivial example
  buffer[i][0] = buffer[i][1] // OK


From doing some research, I suspect there is a possible solution using string  literals to infer number to string or vice versa (as I’ve seen @jcalz propose elsewhere) and then using string manipulation, but the inherent limitation with string manipulation is that I’d have to hard-code some logical grammar (incrementing 8 gives 9 , which incremented gives 10) that could become unwieldy.
Any suggestions?

I'm having trouble understanding your goal from your code snippet. Can you describe your goal, and explain what that code is supposed to be doing in more detail?

Also, that code compiles without errors: https://tsplay.dev/mL0Vem. What exactly is the solution you have preventing you from doing?

Without ms/TS#26382 there's no simple way to do this that works for all use cases.  What are the use cases here? What are the expected inputs? Small non-negative integers? Large integers? Non-integers? Etc etc etc

@jcalz: [1] Thank you for the link, I am looking now. [2] Nice point: short answer is 0, 1, 2, 3, …1024. Long answer is finite, positive integer (w/ 0,-0) representing a number tuple’s cardinality (length → indices) or range (possible number values in that tuple). I imagine the former is the limiting factor up to TypeScript’s tail recursion depth - both if string manipulation is needed, and because there are useful tuple/set type predicates that cannot be described non-recursively. In my case, my desired range (values) is always Base 1024 or below, so I’d be happy with a recursive solution.

Since you're only considering nonnegative integers then see the linked q/a above.

Thank you! Both for the bug link and the dupe thread link. You’ve unblocked me and answered my question.
